# Is there a limit on the maximum number of future jobs queued in an org?

Tags: governorlimits, future

I know there are certain limits with batch jobs, queued jobs, etc., but what about future jobs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no limit to the number of queued Queued or future jobs. However, there are daily [governor limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) to the number of jobs that will run per day (250,000 or 200 times the number of licenses you have, whichever is greater). This limit is cumulative for all types of jobs, including individual counts of Batchable's execute method.

Answer (score 5):

Future , Queueable , Batch and Future are called Async Apex Jobs.

From [Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm):

> The maximum number of asynchronous Apex method executions (batch Apex,
>   future methods, Queueable Apex, and scheduled Apex) per a 24-hour
>   period is 250,000 or the number of user licenses in your org
>   multiplied by 200, whichever is greater

You can run this code to see the limit for your org

```
System.debug(OrgLimits.getMap().get('DailyAsyncApexExecutions').getLimit());
```